# How to load data from api if json changes? Watcher on json? Visualizing data with vue-chartjs and axios

Tags: json, api, vue.js, axios, vue-chartjs

I have built charts with vue-chartjs and fetch data from an api with axios. Currently i have a setInterval to load the JSON every 10 seconds. I want to avoid that and load data only if the json changes. How to do that? I tried to set a watcher on this.chart1Data, but did not work.

Here is the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-chartjs-json-data-rnv2v?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for are WebSockets:

```js
var socket = new WebSocket(urlToWebsocketServer);

// callback method is called when connection is established
socket.onopen = function () {
    console.log("Connection established");
};

// callback method is called when a new websocket messages is received
socket.onmessage = function (messageEvent) {
    console.log(messageEvent.data);
};

// callback method is called when there was an error
socket.onerror = function (errorEvent) {
    console.log("Error! Connection was closed");
};

socket.onclose = function (closeEvent) {
    console.log('Connection closed --- code: ' + closeEvent.code + ' --- reason: ' + closeEvent.reason);
};
```

[I borrowed this code from wikipedia ;)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)

Edit: There are many tutorials out there. Just use Google. [Maybe this one could be helpful](https://tutorialedge.net/javascript/vuejs/vuejs-websocket-tutorial/)

Comment: Just to note, the server will need to be configured to accept websocket connections for this method to work. If you don't have control over this then polling is the only option really.

Comment: Yes, @Hannah is right, my answer assumes you have control over the server. Otherwise there is no better solution then polling.